# Angular Chips not working after updating the model array from javascript

Tags: angularjs

I am using the angular chips library(https://github.com/mohbasheer/angular-chips)  to generate the tags effect. The model that is associated with chips is updated when we add or remove items from UI. But when I change the model from the Javascript, list of items shown on UI is not updated. I have added basic example and created a text box where I am adding elements to array on ng-change. But update in the array is not shown in the UI. Is there any way to use the Angular Chips with two way binding?

Following is the sample code I tried.

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="sample">
    <h4>Basic Example</h4>
    <div ng-controller="basicController as inputdemo">
        <chips ng-model="inputdemo.companies">
            <chip-tmpl>
                <div class="default-chip">
                    {{chip}}
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" remove-chip></span>
                </div>
            </chip-tmpl>
            <input chip-control></input>
        </chips>
        <!-- Printing controller value -->
        <div class="printvalue">
            <b>Controller:</b>
            <div>inputdemo.companies = {{inputdemo.companies}}</div>
        </div>
  <input type="text" ng-model="inputdemo.text" ng-change="inputdemo.textChanged()"/>
    </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    margin: 10px;
}

.loader-container {
    position: relative;
}

.loader-container .loader {
    position: absolute;
    right: 50%;
    bottom: 3px
}

.printvalue{
    margin: 10px;
}
```

Javascript:

```
(function() {
  angular.module('sample',['angular.chips'])
        .controller('basicController', BasicController);

    function BasicController($scope) {
        /*for basic example*/
        this.companies = ['Apple', 'Cisco', 'Verizon', 'Microsoft'];

      this.textChanged=function(){
         this.companies.push('sample');
      };
        /*for bootstrap.ui.typeahead example*/
        this.availableCompanies = ['ACCO Brands',
            'Accuquote',
            'Accuride Corporation',
            'Ace Hardware',
            'Google',
            'FaceBook',
            'Paypal',
            'Pramati',
            'Bennigan',
            'Berkshire Hathaway',
            'Berry Plastics',
            'Best Buy',
            'Carlisle Companies',
            'Carlson Companies',
            'Carlyle Group',
            'Denbury Resources',
            'Denny',
            'Dentsply',
            'Ebonite International',
            'EBSCO Industries',
            'EchoStar',
            'Gateway, Inc.',
            'Gatorade',
            'Home Shopping Network',
            'Honeywell',
        ];
    }
})();
```

Link:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LkgWGw

Thanks.

Comment: Did you achieve the desired output?

Comment: Hi @SateeshKumarAlli, I used md-chips instead of angular-chips. It resolved my issue. :) 
Link: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/chips

Comment: I ended up in writing my own version of chips from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

The desired output can be acheived by using angular.copy every time the model gets updated.

Answer (score 0):

I found an issue with the code. Here is a fix that worked for me: Update the angular-chips.js and replace the `ngModelCtrl.$render` function with:

```
ngModelCtrl.$render = function () {
    if (isDeferFlow && ngModelCtrl.$modelValue) {
        var index, list = [];
        for (index = 0; index < ngModelCtrl.$modelValue.length; index++) {
            if (isPromiseLike(ngModelCtrl.$modelValue[index])) {
                list.push(new DeferChip(ngModelCtrl.$modelValue[index]));
            } else {
                list.push(ngModelCtrl.$modelValue[index]); 
            }
        }
        scope.chips.list = list;
    } else {
        scope.chips.list = angular.copy(ngModelCtrl.$modelValue) || [];
    }
}
```

This change allowed the chip to be pushed into the list when it was an object not a promise.